# Loading an item and storing it for global use

Tags: gui-extensions

I'm trying to load an item within my GUI extension but keep the item in the properties for use later, but i'm having an issue storing the item inside a property array.

My code is farmed out into a 'worker' class

Here's my code to construct and set up my properties array (note the property **p.currentItem**)

```
Namespace.ToolWorker = function ()
{
    this.properties = [];
    var p = this.properties;
    p.itemId = $url.getHashParam("id");
    p.currentItem = null;

};
```

and in my set up method, I load the object like this:

```
Namespace.ToolWorker.prototype._setupContent = function() {
    $log.message("Setting up content");
    var p = this.properties;

    var currentItem = $models.getItem(p.itemId);

    function itemLoaded() {
        $evt.removeEventHandler(currentItem, "load", itemLoaded);
        p.currentItem = currentItem;
    }
    $evt.addEventHandler(currentItem, "load", itemLoaded);

    currentItem.load();
    $j('#currentItemContent').html(p.currentItem.getXml());
}
```

So I store the variable by saying **p.currentItem = currentItem;** but i'm seeing that when using it outside of the **itemLoaded()** the object is null.

It's been a while and i'm likely doing something silly :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are few things:

1. Your last string in which you access `p.currentItem` executes before `itemLoaded()` callback. Thus `p.currentItem` is not defined yet.
2. Storing model item in local variable is anti-pattern. You should never do this. Instead you can store item's ID and always do `$models.getItem([itemID])` to access item. (This is related to built-in marshaling mechanism).

So your code should look like this:

```js
Namespace.ToolWorker.prototype._setupContent = function() {
    $log.message("Setting up content");
    var p = this.properties;

    function itemLoaded(e) {
        var item = $models.getItem(p.itemId);

        if(e) {
            $evt.removeEventHandler(item, "load", itemLoaded);
        }
        $j('#currentItemContent').html(item.getXml());
    }

    var currentItem = $models.getItem(p.itemId);
    if(currentItem.isLoaded(true)) {
        itemLoaded();
    } else {
        $evt.addEventHandler(currentItem, "load", itemLoaded);
        currentItem.load(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @johnwinter Welcome :)